# How to Get the Custom Error Response Text in the HTTP 403 Response

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-status-code-403

I use the following method to make AJAX requests:

```
function getJSON(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.responseType = "json";
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            callback(null, xhr.response);
        } 
        else {
            /*var errorObj = { status: xhr.status, statusText: xhr.statusText };
            callback(errorObj, xhr.response);*/
            callback(xhr.status, xhr.response);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
};
```

I have to get the custom response text from the server if the status is 403. `xhr.response` is null, although I can see the custom error message in the Network tab of the Chromium debugger window. How can I access the custom response text?

Comment: Maybe the [`responseText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText) property?

Comment: Try responseText. (Also possibly dropping responseType if other side is returning different responses based on that)

Comment: Set `responseType` to `text` in the `else` branch? It's been a long time since I used XHR...

Comment: I used JSON.parse(xhr.response) in success branch. Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
            callback(null, xhr.response);
        } else if(xhr.status === 403){
            callback(xhr.status, "not found =(");
         }
        else {
            /*var errorObj = { status: xhr.status, statusText: xhr.statusText };
            callback(errorObj, xhr.response);*/
            callback(xhr.status, xhr.response);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

xhr.responseText should to the trick

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. Explain why this is an answer to the question.